# Manipulate object

Tags: javascript, object

I encountered this while doing exercise 3 from Eloquent JavaScript chapter 4 (http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html).

Basically, it wants me to make a nested list out of an array.

For example, arrayToList([1, 2, 3]) should return as following:

```
var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};
```

My code is slightly different from the right answer in the for loop, but it doesn’t returned the expected result.

My code:

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = {};
  list.value = array[array.length - 1];
  list.rest = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    list.rest = list;
    list.value = array[i];
    }
  return list; 
}
```

Original answer with mild modification to make it look more comparable to my code above:

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = {};
  list.value = array[array.length - 1];
  list.rest = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;
}
```

As you can see, my code is only different from the original answer in the for loop. I wonder why the way I chose to manipulate the object `list` doesn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the problem is that you are *manipulating* the (original) `list` object, overwriting properties on it and so, instead of creating new objects (then overwriting the `list` variable with them).

Comment: Ah, [I knew this was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eloquent+javascript+list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are creating an infinitely recursive object, by assigning the object to one of its fields in doing `list.rest = list;` and since you walk the array backwards, you end up with the first array value as the `value` in that infinitely recursive object; whereas the correct answer is creating a new object each time and using the old object inside.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you do `list = { ... }` you are setting a new type of object to `list`.

Using `list = something` you are changing what list is, but doing `list.something = anotherthing` you are modifying a field from `list`, not what it is.

With your code, `value` is just a field, in the other code, `value` is an array defined earlier, can you see the difference?